# Regular expression for text input

Tags: regex

I want users to be allowed to enter numbers, up to 3 digits before the decimal place, with an optional decimal place and a maximum of 2 digits after the optional decimal place.

I want it to match: 12, 123, 123.5, 123.55, 123.
I do not want it to match: abc, 1234, 123.555

What I have so far it:
^\d{0,3}(.?)\d{0,2}$

At the moment it is still matching 1234. I think I need to use the look behind operator somehow but I'm not sure how.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$
```

Or better, to avoid just a `.`:

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$
```

Specifically, note:

- Escaping the dot, or it matches any character (except new lines), including more digits.
- Made the whole decimal part optional, including the dot. That is - the decimal dot is *not* optional - it must be including if we are to match any digit from the decimal part.
- Even if you have escaped the dot,  `^\d{0,3}(\.?)\d{0,2}$` isn't correct. With the dot optional, it can match `12378`: `\d{0,3}` matches `123`, `(\.?)` doesn't match anything, and `\d{0,2}` matches `78`.

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/OOw6Ucgdgq

Comment: Both work great, but I'll probably use the first one as it's a bit easier to read!. What is the ?: operator doing?

Comment: @Ciaran - Thanks. `(?:  )` is designed to do nothing - it is a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) - a logical group, but its match isn't added to the result of the regex.

Comment: This matches `.` and the empty string as well

Comment: @sln - the first regex does, that's why I added a second one. I try to do one as similar to the OP's as possible, and one from scratch. Note that the OP's regex also accepts an empty input and a single dot - it may be intented. For example, when an input field is empty, you may don't want to display a validation error.

Comment: @Kobi -Well, the first regex was what the OP wanted, too bad you couldn't make that one tennable without alternations. Unfortunate for him he is using it (the first one).

Comment: +1 Correction, this answer looks good. `(?=.*\d)` could be added to the first version to force a value.

Comment: Didn't realise the first one would allow just a period.  Second one it is so, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this (untested)

`^(?=.*\d)\d{0,3}\.?(?<=\.)\d{0,2}$`

**Edit** - the above is wrong.

@Kobi's answer is correct.

A lookahead could be added to his first version to insure a NOT just a dot or empty string.

`^(?=.*\d)\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`

Comment: Not really. `\.?(?<=\.)` reads "optional dot, and then check you're after a dot", which is logically the same as just `\.`. A condition may work  here, but I suspect it's too much, and isn't universally supported. Even without `(?<=\.)`, `(?=.*\d)` protects against `.`, but it can still match `12345`.

Comment: Oh, I missed the optional dot. Nice catch!

Comment: @Kobi, "protects against `.` but can still match `12345`" ? How did you arive at that conclusion? `(?=.*\d)` guarantee's at least a digit. `\.?` is optional, `(?<=\.)` actually protects trailing digits, the `(?: )` group binds the optional `.digits`. You should read it a little closer.

Comment: @sln -  That comment refers to an old version of your answer. I said "Even without `(?<=\.)`" `^(?=.*\d)\d{0,3}\.?\d{0,2}$` can match `12345`. To be honest, I'm not sure you fully understand what `\.?(?<=\.)` does. It is *exactly the same* as `\.`.

Comment: @Kobi -Maybe you didn't see the "untested" in my old version. Thanks for the schooling? How's the new version from 40 minutes ago, got any questions?

Comment: @Kobi - none taken, you were correct though, `\.? (?<=\.)` does mean `\.`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
/^\d{0,2}(?:\d\.|\.\d|\d\.\d)?\d?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the combination of decimal point and the decimal numbers optional. In your regex, only the decimal number is optional. 1234 is accepted because 123 satisfy ^\d{0,3}, not existing decimal point satisfy (.?), and 4 satisfy \d{0,2}.

Kobi's answer provided you the corrected regex.